Rescuing submerged french drains
I have a problem retaining wall, that I've now had to replace twice in 20 years. (I think the flipper who sold the place to us had also replaced it as well).
The latest wall is concrete cinderblock. The contractor installed some french drains behind the wall on the high side to help with drainage.
The problem is the ground behind the retaining walls on the high side has always had a tendency to subside. In this case it took the french drains down with it, and I no longer even know where they are. They're buried.
Now the wall is having trouble with cracking, and the contractor is telling me it would be nice if it had french drains (forgetting he actually installed them!).
What I'm wondering is if I should engage in a little excavation project behind this wall to recover those buried french drains, and if I do, how I prevent this from happening again?

It sounds like you need more structure going back into the hill for that wall to anchor to, or need the wall to be built so it leans into the hill, or both. It also sounds like you may need some drainage designed into the wall so any head of water building up behind it gets released -- "weap holes"  or similar -- since the water may be coming through the ground rather than from the top where a French drain could catch it. Photos of the situation, or at least a sketch, would help.

@keshlam - Really appreciate your expertise on the matter! I'll look into it (Seems like weep holes can be added retroactively?) However, I was particularly wondering in this question if there was something I could/should be doing to retrieve those sunken french drains?

I'm not claiming expertise; this is a comment and ideas to consider, not an answer I am really confident in

Got some pics?  Hopefully the "french drains" were installed with geotextile fabric around the gravel, because if not, that is one reason for subsidence...

@Huesmann - Right now a pic would show some grass that perhaps there might be a french drain buried under. Not sure how that would help. I could try to find and dig up one of them, and then take a picture?

I read up on the fabric gravel barrier when I looked into weep holes yesterday. My memory from pre-pandemic when it was built was that there was definitely gravel put behind the wall. I don't remember the fabric, but I was ignorant enough then that it could have been there and I wouldn't have known what I was looking at.
